# keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: BKS not found

Tags: java, keystore

how to create a .bks keystore in java sun keytool, what should i do?

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\bin>keytool -genkey -alias server3private -ke
ystore server3.private -storetype BKS -keyalg rsa -dname "CN=Your Name, OU=Your
Organizational Unit, O=Your Organization, L=Your City, S=Your State, C=Your Coun
try" -storepass tahirpw -keypass tahirpw
```

**it gives me error**

keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: BKS not found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065379/how-to-create-a-bks-bouncycastle-format-java-keystore-that-contains-a-client-ce

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your error indicates that `keytool` tries to instantiate a `BKS` keystore but no *Cryptographic Service Provider* (CSP) is able to provide such an implementation. `BKS` keystore type is a type implemented by the [BouncyCastle CSP](http://www.bouncycastle.org/).

Therefore there is 2 solutions:

1. install this provider with Java. Oracle published along with Java [a comprehensive documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderInstalling).
2. pass to keytool the suitable options to indicate which CSP should be used and its location:

> ```
> -storetype BKS                                               <- keystore type
> -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider <- CSP implementation
> -providerpath /path/to/bouncycastle.jar                      <- Path to the CSP jar file
> ```

Comment: I have tried your directions using keytool with java for Mac OSX, and get the following error:                         "java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, ?providerpath is not a legal command."                                                           When I try the "keytool -help" though, it shows that "-providerpath" *is* a legal command for -genkeypair command,  so it should work...   Any thoughts on why it won't work for me?   Thanks!

Comment: If anyone else is wondering: `bouncycastle.jar` is the signed **provider** jar file on http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html named `bcprov-[...].jar`