# Android HTTPS Clientnot reading data from socket

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, httpclient

I'm developing an application that will read SSL encrypted string data from a C++ server (presently on my local network), and return information in kind.

I have followed many tutorials and many examples regarding bouncycastle providers, custom socket factories, http clients, and I have got to the point where I am able to send information from the emulator to my c++ server, but the emulator cannot read the data from the socket. Instead I get:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

The server recognizes the handshake and connection, and reads the incoming statement the emulator writes.

The request is being called within an AsyncTask thread

```
private class getXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(NewJobsView.this,"Retrieving Data","Please Wait",true,false);
        pd.setCancelable(true);

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String XML) {
        Log.i("XML:", XML);
        parseXml();
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getXml();
    }   
}
```

This is the request class I'm using (please excuse if it's a bit messy):

```
public class HttpRequest{

    MyHttpClient httpClient;
    HttpContext localContext;
    private String ret;

    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = null;
    Context context = null;   

    int retry = 0;



    public HttpRequest(Context c){
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

        context = c;

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 60000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 60000);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

        httpClient = new MyHttpClient(context);             

        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);       


        httpClient.setParams(params);
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();    
    }


    public void abort() {
        try {
            if (httpClient != null) {
                System.out.println("Abort.");
                httpPost.abort();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MyApp" + e);
        }
    }

    public String sendPost(String url, String data) {
        return sendPost(url, data, null);
    }    

    public String sendPost(String url, String data, String contentType) {
        ret = null; 

        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", data);
        response = null;               

        StringEntity ent = null;        

        try {
            ent = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("MyApp", "HttpUtils : UnsupportedEncodingException : "+e);
        }

        httpPost.setEntity(ent);

        try {

            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            if (response != null) {
                ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.e("MyApp", "HttpUtils: " + ret);
            }
            else{
                abort();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyApp", "HttpUtils: " + e);
        }

        Log.d("MyApp", "Returning value:" + ret);

        if(retry < 3){
            sendPost(url, data);
            retry = retry +1;
        }
        else{
            return ret;
        }

        return ret;

    }  

}
```

A few other notes:

I have

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

in my Manifest file.

I also have verified that the SSL server works, as other clients (albeit C++) are able to maintain a connection and read from the sockets.

the MyHttpClient object is a near replica of

[How to create a BKS (BouncyCastle) format Java Keystore that contains a client certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065379/how-to-create-a-bks-bouncycastle-format-java-keystore-that-contains-a-client-c)

I've been spinning my wheels for a long time, and any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: ... and url adress is ? 10.0.2.2 or localhost ?

Comment: So far, I've found the emulator treats https://192.168.0.100 (my dev box) and https://10.0.2.2 synonymously, so I'm using https://192.168.0.100

Answer (score 0):

check your URL first and one suggestion try to use [httpsconnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)

it is better than normal httpGet as some times it will gives you sockettime / ssl or any other io exception