# KeyStore with BouncyCastleProvider: KeyStore integrity check failed

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, keystore

I want to use a self-signed signature for ssl connections. I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026598/1598840) post.

My problem: After creating the Keystore my integrity-check fails.

```
Keytool-Error: java.io.IOException: KeyStore integrity check failed.
```

I'm still searching but maybe someone can save me some time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Make sure you are using the right password to open the keystore. I was having this error and turns out I was still using the password from the example code in `trusted.load()`

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem where I tried to open a `KeyStore` file I saved locally and 2 reasons comes to mind:

- You are storing your `KeyStore` and loading it with a different password.
- Your `KeyStore` file was damaged some how thus flagging the integrity check.

I'd suggest you try to save and load another file with the same password (fixed) just to see if it will load normally.

Comment: can  you please tell me where its being stored on a mac os ?

Comment: The KeyStore , i even dont know it gets store in android phone or somewhere else

Comment: Are you generating it inside your Android application or before hand?

Answer (score 4):

I have found another corner case that can provoke this message.

I exported a PKCS12 keystore with `openssl` and then tried to import it into an existing keystore with `keytool`. I received the 'integrity check failed' error at this step despite the password being good when I listed the contents of the PKCS12 keystore.

The problem turned out to be because I'd used a password exactly 50 characters long. Although this is accepted by `openssl`, I understand that this is the maximum size of the buffer used and that the last character of the password get overwritten by an 'end of string' character.

Exporting the PKCS12 keystore again with a password of only 49 characters long fixed my issue.

Comment: Exactly the problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your keystore file is properly closed using `FileOutputStream.close()` or it will be marked as having lost integrity