# KeyStore integrity check failed

Tags: android, ssl, bouncycastle, keystore, asmack

I am trying to integrate Facebook Chat in android , so far i have successfully import `asmack` library and i am trying to login using `Facebook JabberID`.

i have mentioned the following configuration to connect it with facebook server but the issue is i am getting following error `KeyStore integrity check failed`

```
06-12 23:18:30.508: W/System.err(2204): java.io.IOException: KeyStore integrity check failed.
06-12 23:18:30.528: W/System.err(2204):     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineLoad(JDKKeyStore.java:888)
06-12 23:18:30.528: W/System.err(2204):     at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:676)
06-12 23:18:30.538: W/System.err(2204):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.KeyStoreManager.getOrCreateKeyStore(KeyStoreManager.java:42)
06-12 23:18:30.548: W/System.err(2204):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.enableEncryption(XMPPConnection.java:880)
06-12 23:18:30.548: W/System.err(2204):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:900)
06-12 23:18:30.608: W/System.err(2204):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:263)
06-12 23:18:30.608: W/System.err(2204):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$1(PacketReader.java:216)
06-12 23:18:30.608: W/System.err(2204):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

here is my code and the `TRUST_STORE_PATH` path is  `/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks`

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = 
       new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);


        Log.d("PATH" ,TRUST_STORE_PATH + " ");

        if (SDK_INT >= 14) {
            config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
            config.setTruststorePassword(null);
            config.setTruststorePath(null);
        } else {
            config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
            config.setTruststorePath(TRUST_STORE_PATH);
        }
```

i really dont have any idea about this error and how to get rid off it , i saw following thread but no luck

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125609/keystore-with-bouncycastleprovider-keystore-integrity-check-failed)

Comment: Is it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13737447/623999)?

Comment: Probably the password to open the keystore is incorrect.
see this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125609/keystore-with-bouncycastleprovider-keystore-integrity-check-failed/13737447#13737447