# Can the Bouncy Castle cryptography API be used in Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am writing an application for the Android platform which makes use of cryptography. Is it possible for the Bouncy Castle cryptography API to be used in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact, it is already partly included (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3280). To get the full functionality, use [Spongy Castle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however do not use Spongy Castle please. See [How to add Bouncy Castle algorithm to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584401/how-to-add-bouncy-castle-algorithm-to-android) for a complete example on using Bouncy Castle on Android.