# BouncyCastle on Android

Tags: android, encryption, bouncycastle

I am using PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC to encrypt binary data which contains sensitive user data

I just want to confirm if BouncyCastle is part of every Android SDK after (2.1) as I read a on a few sites that BouncyCastle is not part of every Android SDK.

Would like a definitive answer

Answer (score 12):

You can also try the SpongyCastle library which is a precompiled build of BouncyCastle but tested with Android.

https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle

Comment: If you're interested in SpongyCastle, it hasn't been updated since v1.58 whereas BouncyCastle is currently on v1.62.  You can build your own SC/BC jar for Android from BC sources using "mybc". Link to my GitHub repo: https://github.com/jbuhacoff/nodejs-mybc-util

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle is not a part of Android SDK. You can download it separately and add it to your project.

In [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584401/how-to-add-bouncycastle-algorithm-to-android) you can fine guid how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle modified version is a part of Android SDk.

Android includes a modified version of the Bouncy Castle Api.