# Using Java SDK in Android app

Tags: android, sdk, bouncycastle, spongycastle

So the app I'm building has to use a specific library. Unfortunately this library uses bouncycastle in it. As is known this will not work with Android. Are there any ways to get around this? I was suggested to build a service layer to interact with the library SDK but I have no idea where to begin or what that really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding and modifying the source code of the SDK to implement spongycastle

Answer (score 0):

If the library comes in a packed .jar file you can import it to your Android project by right clicking on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries tab and pressing the Add external JAR button

This is valid for Eclipse, there way to do it on Android Studio might be different.

This post may also solve your issue: [BouncyCastle on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397557/bouncycastle-on-android)

Comment: Importing is not the problem. Bouncycastle down not work on Android. I need a service layer or a workaround

Comment: On the post I sent there is a link to SpongyCastle library which is a wrapped version of the BouncyCastle that should work on Android: https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle

Comment: I don't think you get the whole question. I have a .jar library. This library has bouncy castle, xapo SDK, and other utilities inside. Because it has bouncy castle integrated in it, it does not work with Android. I'm trying to figure out how to use a service layer to interact with the SDK so it will work or any other workaround