# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/spongycastle/util/Strings Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, security, rsa

```
 import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
   Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
                    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ESDSA", "BC");
                    publicKeyServer = (ECPublicKey) factory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytePubKeyServer));
```

This is the code I try to add the bounycastleProvider. The bouncycastle Jar don't work on Android so I saw that I need to use the spongy castle jar. So I have added the spongy castle jar now I am stuck.
In this code I try to convert bytes to a public key.

This is the error message

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/spongycastle/util/Strings
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:bctls-jdk15on:1.58.0.0'
    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you added Spongycacstle in your Gradle configuration as library? Please edit your question and add the line where you add Spongycastle in gradle.

Comment: Yeah I have added my gradle build script

Comment: As there is not Spongycastle entry you have place the JAR fil in the `libs` folder? Don't do that, just add Spongycastle as gradle dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323575/150978 Spongycastle library will then be automatically downloaded and added to your project. Delete the jar file in the libs folder.

Comment: But it dont' work i have updated the build.gradle

Comment: You have added the dependencies to the buildscript section of your project. Instead you have to add it to the dependencies section of the gradle config of your app. Please learn the basics of Android Studio/Gradle: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies